# Automatically toggle the wifi on (or airplane mode off) for certain application status (focus or non focus)

Tags: windows-10, battery

I have to use a laptop and sadly in a location we don't have the luxury to use the power, so we rely on the battery. We all accept that the meeting can either run it's course or until a laptop runs out of battery. For the foreseeable future there is no sensible fix, as such, I need to preserve the battery as much as possible.

I have noticed that airplane mode saves a lot of power because when it's enabled, my laptop lasts considerably longer. At the moment, I'm manually enabling/disabling flight mode in order to consume as little power as possible when I don't need wifi access.

My question is, can this wifi/airplaine mode toggling be done in an automated way on my Windows 10 machine. Am I able to configure it so if I do certain things (eg, make a web browser active/focused, then airplane mode is disabled), when it becomes in-active, it becomes enabled again.

I could write a batch file which simply enables wifi/disables airplane mode and then loads the browser and use this batch file instead of accessing the browser direct, but that doesn't solve the issue for when it's closed, or lost focused.

I'm not fussed if the toggle is by wifi or airplane mode (airplane mode is preferable). Obviously the software which can do this can't take up too much resource or that will defeat the purpose.

Does anything like this already exist?